# How to load pdf from url without downloading

Tags: android

I am trying to load a pdf fetched from a server in my webview android without downloading the pdf.
My code

```
 String pdf_url = Uri.encode(getIntent().getStringExtra("pdf_url"));
        webView = findViewById(R.id.pdf_viewer);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pdf_progress);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf_url);
```

The problem is sometimes the pdf is showing fine but many times its showing a blank screen,'
Everytime the method onPageFinished() is triggered as my progressBar gets invisible , but pdf only shows sometimes , not always . Is there a sure solid method to get the pdf every time? Please help!

Comment: `trying to load a pdf fetched from a server in my webview android without downloading the pdf.` First: A WebView cannot display a .pdf document. Second: Of course you have to download that document as if it is on a server you should download it to your Android device. How would you ever see it at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked best for me,
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

```
private void setPdf(URL url) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream;
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    openPdf(inputStream);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openPdf(InputStream inputStream) {
        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .onLoad(loadCompleteListener)
                .enableAntialiasing(true)
                .load();


    }

    OnLoadCompleteListener loadCompleteListener = new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dependency
Easy to use

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MuPDF` library for properly viewing a PDF file on any standard Android operating System.

**Example Code:**

```
import com.artifex.sonui.editor.DocumentView

fun presentDocument(documentUri:Uri) {
    val documentView:DocumentView = findViewById(R.id.doc_view)
    documentView.start(documentUri, 0, true)
}
```

**Library url:**

https://mupdf.com/appkit/docs/mupdf-android-getting-started

**Getting started:**

https://mupdf.com/appkit/docs/mupdf-android-pdf-viewing

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the page until it displays the pdf:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
if (view.getContentHeight() == 0)
    view.reload();
}
```

Comment: i tried this but the view never reloads .

Comment: The same blank screen appears